# Оборот "не так ли"

Tags: пунктуация

Оборот "не так ли" нужно выделять запятой?

Answer (score 1):

***Современный толковый словарь русского языка Т.Ф.Ефремовой*** - "НЕ ТАК ЛИ":
***Частица разг.*** Употр. при ожидании утвердительного ответа на вопрос; не правда ли.

Обычно эта частица завершает высказывание, стоит в конце предложения. Запятая в этом случае **ставится**. ***Ты запомнила всё, не так ли?***

Если "не так ли" является частью предложения и служит обстоятельством, то запятыми этот оборот ***не выделяется***: ***Не так ли и ты, Русь, что бойкая необгонимая тройка, несешься?*** Несёшься КАК? так.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от контекста.

Comment: Например: Интресный фильм, не так ли? Сенсация, не так ли? В подобных вариантах должна же быть запятая?

Comment: Да, в этих случаях должна.